# How to write TFS API using pseudo code?

Tags: sharepoint, tfs, sharepoint-2010

I am just wondering is it possible to test the **TFS API** given in the Microsoft website to test the API whether it's working or not? If so is it possible with pseudo code? Can you guide me? I need to test it before i implement it. Or do you have other ways to test the API?

This are the [TFS API](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/wit/work-items#create-a-work-item) I am going to test whether it's working,
I need to make sure the API are available in sharepoint to use

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is no such Microsoft website to test the API or any pseudo code to handle it.

You could submit a [uservoice](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-visual-studio-team-services) here, and there has been a similar one:

> **Enable to impersonate user in Rest API**
>
> https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-visual-studio-team-services/suggestions/17996818-enable-to-impersonate-user-in-rest-api

However, for the API you are using--**Create a work item**, there is an alternative way to verify whether the work item field could be created or not. By using **op**   parameter:

[image]

Use *`test`* to verify that the value is valid **without actually saving the work item.**